# Is there an option to block local network access for apps?

Tags: applications, wi-fi, networking, permissions

I'm trying to prevent apps from accessing other devices on the same network (LAN). Something similar to this iOS setting.

[image]

Some searching led me to this feature in Express VPN.

[image]

Is there a way to do this in Android Settings or using a non-VPN app?

Answer (score 0):

My LAN is protected by firewalls. That's the only real solution if you want a real protection. Each computer on the LAN can have its own firewall preventing connections from the outside. Only let the very connections you are interested in happen (if any, I like to have access to my local Apache2 where I store some info. I like to access).

It will always be possible to circumvent protections on a phone if you're a good hacker. Firewalls on the other end requires a possible hack to penetrate that computer, somehow. Not very likely if you do not have any services (completely block all traffic) since that would mean an exploit in the firewall/network stack.